# My simple PHP includes aren't being parsed

Tags: php

I'm fairly decent with HTML and CSS, but I'm a total noob to PHP. I'm trying to set up a really basic PHP template on my website, which is currently at http://www.paulgrantdesign.com/test77/photography

If you use Inspect Element on the page, it looks commented out in Chrome, or isn't even visible in Firefox, so you might have to view source. But I added the line

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

near the top. The php file exists, which contains a copied and pasted section of what was there before. When everything was in place just in the html file, it looked great. How come the PHP isn't including the file I'm asking it to?

Comment: PHP is supposed to get parsed on server side, so you should never see PHP code in your browser. You will have to set up your web server to parse PHP source code inside the HTML page - usually by giving the page a .php extension, but other options are available as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `index.html` page is not being parsed by the PHP processor. PHP is not, alas, magical. It's actually a program that's run by the server on files containing PHP code. When a client requests a PHP page, the source of the pages file is sent to the PHP program for pre-processing, and the output is streamed to the client. Hence the (recursive) name: PHP stands for **PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor**.

So, for `<?php ?>` blocks to be handled, the server must know which files that contains them, so it can be run them through PHP on the server side. Any file that's not will just send the code straight to the browser, uninterpreted. Depending on your server setup, you might be able to fix this by renaming `index.html` to `index.php`, adding a filetype handler for `.html` to be parsed by `php`, or several other solutions too numerous to go into. Check with your host!

Answer (score 2):

The page where you have the `<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>` code, needs to be a .php file as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Your file is not treated as a PHP file, it is sent as-is by the server (this is a static page).

Try renaming your index.html to index.php.